# Where to air layer relative to the nodes

Tags: propagation, air-layer

Where is the correct position for air layer propagation relative to the leaf nodes? After watching a dozen Youtube videos, they all have different suggestions. Which position is truly the best?

- [This video suggests to strip the bark **below the node**](https://youtu.be/rOjf7LliPmM?t=402).
- [This video suggests to strip the bark **right on the node**](https://youtu.be/8f1m1IuonRU?t=153)
- [This video makes **no suggestion** on relative positioning](https://youtu.be/jynKq8PnBtE?t=305).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the plant involved where roots are most readily produced. There are lots of pictures of Pothos rooting in water showing that for this plant the nodes produce roots quickly. When propagating grape vines we take short cuttings with the node at the top, then damage the internode which then produces roots leaving the node to provide the shoot only. So individual cases (videos) may all be correct for the material involved. Do you have a plant in mind?

Comment: I will attempt to air layer a Longan. Are the positioning suggestions grouped by species, genus, or family, .....?

Comment: There are a few Youtube videos specifically on air layering longan. The one I saw stripped bark for about 4 cm., that will include mostly internode and possibly a node but I don't think it is necessary to do so.

Comment: What's the science behind different trees needing different relative positioning? I thought the nodes serve more or less the same biological purpose on all trees.